# Jquery / javascript : about calling other js files from one js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been asked to make a wordpress site out of an html template wich uses some *javascript*.
I'm not really familiar with `js`, but it is already been written so it shouldn't really make a problem.
But there is something I cannot figure out, wich I guess it has to be really simple.

Normally I call my `js` and `css` files from the *wordpress* `header.php` like (for example):

`<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>`

so I use  `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` as templateurl..

But in this template I have gotten there is a js file that calls other `js` files, and I can't write `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` there ofcourse.

It looks like this:

```
    document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ path +'some_js_file.js"></script>');
```

And my browser doesn't load this because it don't know where to look.
How can I tell my browser where this file is, so that my js is working again??

I have already tried filling in the whole url of the `js` file, and I have also tried to just call that files in de `header.php`

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a sidenote, you should generally be using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) when inserting scripts in Wordpress, not add them to the PHP directly.

Comment: See where the `path` variable is set in your js file and modify it.

Comment: why you cant preinclude second js file in header.php?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone, but I found out the things I tried  weren´t  working because of jquery, when I removed jQuery it worked again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the template url as a variable in the javascript on your page.  Subsequent javascript files that your page loads should be able to access the same variable.

```
<script>
    var template_url="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
</script>
```

Then later on you can just use that variable:

```
$('#something').html("<img src='"+template_url+"/rest/of/path.jpg'>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I found out the things I tried  weren´t  working because of jquery, when I removed jQuery it worked again..